# Add a JPanel in a BorderPane

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jlabel, stage

I have a **Java** project that plays a **.flv media file** through **JavaFX Media Player**, and it's working fine. Recently, I've been wanting to experiment by adding **GUI components** to this Project *(JPanel, JLabel)*. However, I've failed in all my attempts and after doing some research turns out it's not as simple as i first thought.. I've tried *borderPane.setTop(JLabel)* but I get a **"Cannot convert Jlabel to Node"** error.. I feel that I'm missing something

If anyone has any idea why this isnt working for me, I would greatly appreciate any form of explanation or examples.. :)

Here is the code if it might be of use to you!

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage){
    String path = "Data/Video/Clip.flv";
    Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(mediaView);

    //borderPane.add(logoPanel);                            <<<<<<< Error

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1024, 800);
    scene.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);

    stage.setTitle("Media Player");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
```

Comment: Do you really want to mix Swing (`JPanel`, `JLabel`, etc) with JavaFX (`MediaPlayer`, `BorderPane`)? Doing that is difficult and requires working with two different toolkits and two different UI threads. Is there a really pressing reason why you can't just build the UI using only JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want to achieve: add some Swing components to an JavaFX application.

You have to use [SwingNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) class to "wrap" a [JComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html).

> **SwingNode Class**
>
> JavaFX 8 introduces the SwingNode class, which is located in the
>   javafx.embed.swing package. This class enables you to embed Swing
>   content in a JavaFX application. To specify the content of the
>   SwingNode object, call the setContent method, which accepts an
>   instance of the javax.swing.JComponent class.

You can check [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm) how embed Swing component into JavaFX application.

**Small example to put a Swing `Button` into the center of a `BorderPane`**:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
            JButton jButton = new JButton("I am a Swing button");
            jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Message from Swing");

                }
            });
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swingNode.setContent(jButton);
                }
            });

            root.setCenter(swingNode);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**By the way, `BorderPane` has no method "add" (as in your commented line):**

You can use [setCenter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#setCenter-javafx.scene.Node-), [setTop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#setTop-javafx.scene.Node-), [setBottom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#setBottom-javafx.scene.Node-), [setLeft](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#setLeft-javafx.scene.Node-) and [setRight](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#setRight-javafx.scene.Node-) to add `Nodes` into it (as you used to fill the center).

**If your goal was not to embed Swing into JavaFX**, just to use JavaFX controls, you can check [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/jfxpub-ui_controls.htm) what controls JavaFX has by default.

Comment: Note that if you are going to mix Swing and JavaFX, you need to use the correct threads for each toolkit. The button needs to be created, or at least added to the `SwingNode`, on the AWT Event Dispatch thread. In the code sample here, you are adding it on the JavaFX Application Thread, which violates [Swing's threading rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @James_D, you are totally right. Updated the sample to set the content of the `SwingNode` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Answer (score 0):

BorderPane is a JavaFX Node whereas JPanel is a Java Swing Component.

You cannot add a JPanel to a BorderPane, what you are looking for instead is the JavaFX equivalent of the JPanel which is the [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) class.

If you are developing using JavaFX it is easier to just use JavaFX components. If you **must** use Swing components then you can use the [SwingNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) class.